# Maven: copying directories using exec plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I'm having trouble using the Maven exec plugin to copy the contents of one directory to another.  Sadly, when I include this plugin in my pom.xml …

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>cp</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-r</argument>
            <argument>web-app/*</argument>
            <argument>src/main/webapp</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It isn't working.  I get the error below …

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (default-cli) on project jx: Result of /bin/sh -c cd /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mycoUSA2/Technology/nna/myco2usa/jx && cp -r 'web-app/*' src/main/webapp execution is: '1'. -> [Help 1]
```

Does anyone know how I can modify my plugin config to copy the contents of one directory to another?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: The first questions comes to my mind: Why do you need that? In which relationship do you need this? (Looks like a webapp?; exploded using of a webapp?); You are violating the rule not to change/modify the src folder by any build...

Comment: Ever tried deploying a Mavenized Grails app to an embedded Jetty server and configuring a second context path?  Now you're like, "What the hell are you talking about?"  That's why I asked the simpler question above.

Comment: I assume that you need the second context for Unit/Integrationg testing? Yes than you the maven-jetty-plugin into different life-cycle-phases with different configurations).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bash, try the following:

```
<executable>bash</executable>
<arguments>
    <argument>-c</argument>
    <argument>cp -r web-app/* src/main/webapp</argument>
</arguments>
```

This spawns a new bash and gives it the command `cp -r web-app/* src/main/webapp` to execute.

You can also test if it works for you by inputting this into a normal Terminal window first:

`bash -c "cp -r web-app/* src/main/webapp"`

Note that the `"` signs do make a difference as the `exec-maven-plugin` does insert them automatically, thus they are not included in the `<argument>`-tag.

Answer (score 1):

Note the command it ran. From the error output:

```
cp -r 'web-app/*' src/main/webapp
```

Note in particular the `'web-app/*'` file it has tried to copy. Because it has quoted this argument the `cp` command is looking for a specific file with the name `*` in the web-app directory. Because you don't have a file with this name it has exited with the error code `1`.

The maven-resources-plugin has a goal designed to perform this task. Why not give it a try? It would have the added benefit of making your build platform independent.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/web-app</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>web-app</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. mvn -X might be more revealing
2. Many people would use the maven-antrun-plugin and script this in ant so as to get a portable solution.